# Trying to plot this probability

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

Can anyone help me plot this?

log P(X >= x) = alpha logx

x=0.001 + k(0.001)

k= 0, ..., 100

I can't figure out the coding for this.. I've been trying this for a while, and can't seem to figure it out. I believe this is a stable distribution, but the built in function doesn't seem to have x^(alpha) so it's making me extra confused.

Can anyone help me out?
Thank you.

Comment: Could you clarify what is the PDF or CDF of your distribution ?

Comment: Which built in functions have you been using ?

Comment: This is all my research professor told me to do.. I'm a bit confused myself as to which to show. BUT I need log P(X >= x) on the y axis and alpha logx on the x axis.

Comment: I've been trying to use the StableDistribution function, and I don't entirely know what to put in for the other four variables.. That's all my research professor had told me.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) [`Read the FAQs`](http://tinyurl.com/cacvex2)!  3) When you see good Q&A, vote them up by [`clicking the gray triangles`](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.  ALSO, remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [`by clicking the checkmark sign`](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define a function

```
f[x_] := Probability[X > x, X \[Distributed] StableDistribution[1, 1.3, -1, 0, 2]]
```

Because alpha is not given, lets plot it for a few values of alpha:

```
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[Log[{x^#, f[x]}] & /@ Range[-1.5, 1.5, .45]], {x, -2, 2}, 
                AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> True, Axes -> False]
```

[image]

`StableDistribution` looks like this:

```
Plot[Evaluate@Table[PDF[StableDistribution[1, 1.3, \[Beta], 0, 2], 
    x], {\[Beta], {-1, 0, 1}}], {x, -12, 12}, Filling -> Axis]
```

[image]

Comment: There are so many different competing definitions of the Stable Distribution in the literature (I am familiar with at least 5 different definitions in standard texts), it is rather fanciful to suggest that the above represents 'the solution' to anything of relevance. It appears the question is deficient.

Comment: @ColinRose I merely show how to use symbolic `Probability` function (cool mma feature) to make a plot of `log P(X >= x) = alpha log x` . The particular distribution is irrelevant. The question is deficient, agree, but the answer isn't. Trying to do my best by what's given, - giving such insights to beginners is not a bad idea. They can addopt approach to any other distribution. I am a bit surprised by the down-vote.

Comment: Thank you guys for your help! I really appreciate it. Colin, I was also confused about how I was supposed to go about this. But all my professor said was to plot the given equation above and to play around with the alpha values.. I really appreciate everyone's help though!